# Creating an object without using new, or Activitor or compiled lambdas

Tags: c#, oop

I'm currently involved in trying to create a method that will accept X number of objects that implement a particular interface.  However for readability I was not wanting to use the new keyword to create the object.

For example, my code would look like:

```
var builder = new MyBuilder();
builder.Build(Value("Andre", "Like", "Test"),
              Value("Bob", "and", "Andre"));
```

That is what I am looking for.  I'm trying to avoid having to do:

```
var builder = new MyBuilder();
builder.Build(new Value("Andre", "Like", "Test"),
              new Value("Bob", "and", "Andre"));
```

or even

```
var builder = new MyBuilder();
builder.Build(Value.Create("Andre", "Like", "Test"),
              Value.Create("Bob", "and", "Andre"));
```

I realise that in this example it doesn't seem any reason to do what I want, but looking past the example is there any way I can do what I want?  Perhaps using creating a struct and using the operator overload?

Value in this case could be a class, or struct as long as they implement some interface that the Build method accepts.

If this is too vague I can try and give a better description.

Comment: Make the Create function a member of the containing class (or one of its bases) maybe?

Comment: @PMF  I'm hoping to use MyBuilder in lots of places.  Would that still make that an option?

Comment: First example looks like calling a method. So why don't you listen to what PMF wrote and do not create a *method* which then can call `Builder`, create `new`, etc. Moving repeatable code into a private method of the class is very useful.

Comment: @dreza: No, not so easily. If it is required in different classes, you always need a `new` or at least one static method with a class qualifier.

Comment: @PMF ok thanks, that's sort of what I thought but you never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having that API you need to have a `Value` method that returns a `new Value()`.

If you want to use it in several places, maybe you can change the API to be:

```
var builder = new MyBuilder();
builder.Build().Value("Andre", "Like", "Test")
               .Value("Bob", "and", "Andre");
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense as it is, but you can have something like

```
var builder = new MyBuilder();
builder.BuildValue("Andre", "Like", "Test")
       .Value("Bob", "and", "Andre");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static method called Value that does the new for you:

```
public static T Value<T>() where T : IInterface, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

If your T requires dynamic constructor parameters, you could use reflection to call the constructor instead.

The method could even be a get property instead.

Edit: To answer your comment below, I know you said no Activator but this is all I can think of:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IInterface Value(this Type type)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IInterface;
    }
}
```

The above has no namespace, so any class can use it. Example below:

```
var test = typeof(Test).Value();
```

Comment: Ok, but that would require the static method to be either in every class where I'm doing this, or I would be using the static method such as MyClass.Value().  Can I do this without having to have the class prefix?

Comment: @dreza does the extension help you at all? I'm not too sure why you think that writing the new keyword is such a hassle though?

Comment: @dreza You could take the first **T Value** method I wrote, and make it a method on the **Builder** class, then after you create the new object inside the builder class you add it to that Build method.